# nlohmann/json library with intel pin

Tags: c++, json, profiling, reverse-engineering, intel-pin

I want to use [`nlohmann/json`](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases) library with my intel pin tool.

As directed in the document, I downloaded the `json.hpp` file and I'm including that in the pin tool. But, I am getting a bunch of errors something like (when I try to `make`):

```
$head error.log
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h:2452,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/initializer_list:41,
                 from json.hpp:42,
                 from inscount0.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/array:40,
                 from json.hpp:60,
$ less error.logs
$ head error.logs
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h:2452,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/initializer_list:41,
                 from json.hpp:42,
                 from inscount0.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/array:40,
                 from json.hpp:60,
```

These are just few examples, though there are too many errors like these (I can post the whole error log file if someone wants). I am sure there must be some type conflict.

I also tried to use this library with a simple `cpp` code and it worked fine. I don't know what I am missing here.

> Edit:

My code:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
> #include "pin.H"
> #include "json.hpp"
>
> ofstream OutFile;
>
> // The running count of instructions is kept here
> // make it static to help the compiler optimize docount
> static UINT64 icount = 0;
>
> // This function is called before every instruction is executed
> VOID docount()
> {
>   icount++;
> }
>
> // Pin calls this function every time a new instruction is encountered
> VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
> {
>     // Insert a call to docount before every instruction, no arguments are passed
>     INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)docount, IARG_END);
> }
>
> KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool",
>     "o", "inscount.out", "specify output file name");
>
> // This function is called when the application exits
> VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
> {
>   std::cout << icount << '\n';
>   /*
>     // Write to a file since cout and cerr maybe closed by the application
>     OutFile.setf(ios::showbase);
>     OutFile << "Count " << icount << endl;
>     OutFile.close();
>   */
> }
>
> INT32 Usage()
> {
>     cerr << "This tool counts the number of dynamic instructions executed" << endl;
>     cerr << endl << KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() << endl;
>     return -1;
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char * argv[])
> {
>     // Initialize pin
>     if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();
>
>     OutFile.open(KnobOutputFile.Value().c_str());
>
>     // Register Instruction to be called to instrument instructions
>     INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);
>
>     // Register Fini to be called when the application exits
>     PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);
>
>     // Start the program, never returns
>     PIN_StartProgram();
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Note that this is a simple pin tool (exactly the same example used in the documentation) which counts the number of instructions (see the [`documentation`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/index.html)). The example is working fine, without the inclusion of "json.hpp".

Comment: I know for a fact that nlohman's json code is correct (I use it in my codebase extensively). The issue is most likely in your code, which you conveniently didn't show.

Comment: my code is working fine without the library - but when I try to include it - #include<json.hpp> it gives me errors, so I don't see a problem with my code here. Also, I know that the code is correct (that's why i mentioned that it worked fine with the simple cpp code but not when I include it in my pin tool).

Comment: @SergeyA I updated the question with the example.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691080/intel-pin-with-c14). Intel PIN comes with its own STL library that is not compatible with C++11.

Comment: Thanks rustyx, in that case is it not possible to use this library with pin (forgive my ignorance)?